# no match for ‘operator<<’ error when overloading output operator and post increment operator

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, constants, overloading, operator-keyword

When I try to compile the following code, the compiler generates a long paragraph of error message, saying something like "  no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘std::cout << a.A::operator++(0)’ " ... "candidates are...."

But if I change the type of the second parameter of operator<< to "const A&" or simply "A", it magically compiles.

Why does this change work? Does the c++ standard force the type of the second parameter to be either const T& or T when << is overloaded? Or there are some other reasons?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
public:
    A operator++(int) { return A(); }
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& os,  A& a)
{
    return os;
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    cout << a++;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't bind a temporary to a non-`const` reference. Will dig up a suitable link.

Comment: No, it's not specific to `operator<<`, it's just typically pointless to give something you'll never see again to a function that needs to be able to change that.

Answer (score 4):

What you're missing is that `operator++` returns a temporary value. It has to increment the value yet still return the original, so what it does is save off a copy of the original, then increment it, then return the original value copy.

This copy is return as an unnamed temporary, and the language states that such values can't be bound to non-const references (as your parameter). You don't want to pass to an output function as non-const reference anyway as if you mutated the value during output your users would be extremely disappointed.

Comment: Thanks for detailed explanation. I know normally we should pass const reference to output function to avoid accidentally changing the value. Here I just couldn't understand why non-const reference will cause error. But after reading the answers and comments, I think I understand. Temporary is like some kind of constant, so it cannot be bound to non-const reference. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

You can't initialize non-const references with r-values. Your `operator++` returns an r-value. There are two ways:

Define you `<<` operator as

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const A& a)
```

or pass l-value

```
A b = a++;
cout << b;
```

Comment: Or add an `operator<<` that takes `A&&`